# Doing a cross dissolve on a UIImage inside a animateAlongsideTransition block

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have added an animation to a `UINavigationController` transition, which involves repositioning a `UIImageView`:

```
transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    myImageView.frame = newFrame
}, completion: {
    // ...
})
```

This code lives inside `viewWillAppear(_:)`. This code works fine so far. However, I don't just want to change the frame of the image view, I also want to change the image using a cross dissolve. I've tried this:

```
transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    myImageView.frame = newFrame
    UIView.transitionWithView(boardImageView,
        duration: context.transitionDuration(),
        options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
        animations: {
            myImageView.image = newImage
    }, completion: nil)
}, completion: {
    // ...
})
```

This doesn't work though - it simply changes the image of the image view (without cross dissolving) after the animation is completed. Is there a way to do the cross dissolve during the transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do manually what the transition would have done. Before the `animateAlongsideTransition` call, put a new image view into the interface in the same position as the old one, with `alpha` of `0`. In the animation, change its `alpha` to `1` and the `alpha` of the old image view to `0`, thus visibly performing the cross dissolve. (Do any other animations here as well, of course.) In the completion block, remove the old (now invisible) image view.